# Magento base url empty

Tags: cache, base-url, js-css

We have a very awkward and frustrating problem with our Magento store.

After several hours (sometimes days, sometimes a few hours) our site get broken (CSS and JS are not loaded anymore). We found out that it has something to do with the Magento base_url. When the problem occures the my CSS and JS are missing the prefix base_url. After I flush the cache the base urls are restored and the website is functioning normally again.

We use Lesti FPC.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Magento's default cache. This should fix the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63408)

Comment: Edited my answer. Happy?

Comment: Running your website without cache is not a solution to a problem. What the OP wants is a fast website, by using cache. But this strange thing happens and he is posting that here on Magento SE hoping to find an answer that is a bit more comprehensive than yours.

Comment: @Wouter has mentioned that they are using Lesti FPC, If you are not aware of this, it is full page caching that confilcts with Magento's default cache and shouldnt be ran alongside of it. So please dont try a bully someone who has lower rep than you becasue you're not always right and as simple as the answer may be, there is a good chance that it will fix the problem.

Comment: Well, that is actually a very good explanation. Please add that to your answer

Comment: The strange thing is we use lesti for 2 years now together with magento's default caching without any troubles. We also use lesti on other shops without this problem.

Comment: Try it and let me know if it works

Comment: So I need to disable all magento caching items and leave lesti on?

Comment: I have to test this for one or two weeks before I know if it is working.

Comment: Hi, just got the strange thing again, after flushing the cache te website was up again. Any other ideas? Or could you help me fixing it?